# Abs(sum of differences of elements in a sorted array) = array.Max()-array.Min() Why?

Tags: arrays, mathematical-analysis, mathematical-programming

I just found out by luck that

```
 Abs(sum of differences of elements in a sorted array) = array.Max()-array.Min()
```

For example,
Consider a sorted array, {1 43 65 97 98 99 101}

Abs(1-43-55-97-98-99-101)= 101-1

Does anyone know why?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [Yes](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6258/lining-up-recruits). Just write it out...

Comment: Higher character encodes higher value.
b - a = -(a - b), since array is in ascending order than abs is not needed, simple minus suffice.
But why it works for more elements?
c - b + b - a = -(a - b + b - c)
And this just encodes consecutive differences of sorted elements. I hope you see the pattern.

Comment: Re: "Abs(1-43-55-97-98-99-101)= 101-1": This is not true.

Comment: What does this have to do with computer science, except that you chose to say "array" rather than "sequence of integers"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you picture these as distances along a road, it should be very intuitive.

If (for example) you start at kilometer #7, then proceed through kilometers #45, #81, and #97, then the distances you travel are 45−7, then 81−45, then 97−81; and the total distance you travel is 97−7. Since the total distance is the sum of the individual distances, 97−7 = (45−7) + (81−45) + (97−81).

This only works for a sorted set, because otherwise you have backtracking, where you cover a certain distance and then "un-cover".

Comment: That's an excellent explanation. For completeness, you should probably say "[telescoping sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html)" and observe that, in $97-81+81-45+45-7$, everything except the first and last term cancels.